# Gradle Sync Faild ResolvedArtifact

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDgn4.png)

**What is the cause of this error? (See Attach Photo)**

```
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0, variantName=null, artifactFile=C:\\Users\\SCS\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\androidx.activity\\activity\\1.8.0\\4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca\\activity-1.8.0.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={\__current_build_\_=D:\\Android\\Projects\\Mehrdasht}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@27ca8c0e)
```

Comment: Please **DO NOT** attach images of code. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your code as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](//idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)